# Is it possible to use self.value as default argument in method?

Tags: python, self

I would like to use element defined in class `__init__` as default argument of some other method. Here is my code:

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 3

    def print_element(self, element=self.value):
        print(element)

main = Main()
main.print_element()
```

It generates error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Main():
  File "so.py", line 5, in Main
    def print_element(self, element=self.value):
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can use an instance attribute value as a default.  You can work around it by defaulting to `None`, then doing the rest inside the function:

```
def print_element(self, element=None):
    if element is None:
        element = self.value
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this: the default value is evaluated when you define the function.

Your run-time logic appears to be

- if `element` is passed in, print that
- else, print the current `self.value`

You can get this with a conditional inside the method.

```
def print_element(self, element=None):

    print(element if element else self.value)
```

Is that brief enough to suit your purposes?